# How Do i fix Input String was not in a correct format

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm Setting up a cross platform App.  how do I make the input string be in a correct format

This is a Xamarim.forms project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
 x:Class="TestProjectXamarin.Views.DetailViews.InfoScren1">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout x:Name="MainLayout">
        <RelativeLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout x:Name="SubLayout"
                         Orientation="Vertical"
                         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=e}"
                         RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=e}">
                <Label Text="Let's see the bla bla bla Over Here" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>

            </StackLayout>

            <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True" Color="Gray" x:Name="ActivitySpinner"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=width, Factor=0.45}"
                               RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.45}"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

I expected the code to be error free but it tells me Input string was not in a correct format

Comment: Is this a compiler error or a run-time error?  Does it specify a line number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are assigning `Constant=e`, and Constant must get a value.

> Constant – the value to use as an offset of the value.

Also, in your ActivityIndicator, the property is `Width`.

Here is your sample working. Adjust the Constant value according to your needs.

```
 <StackLayout x:Name="MainLayout">
        <RelativeLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout x:Name="SubLayout"
                         Orientation="Vertical"
                         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=1}"
                         RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=1}">
                <Label Text="Let's see the bla bla bla Over Here" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>

            </StackLayout>

            <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True" Color="Gray" x:Name="ActivitySpinner"
                               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                               RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.45}"
                               RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=0.45}"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </StackLayout>
```

For more information about RelativeLayouts, check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout)

Comment: Please I have added offset value to the constants  it does not seem to resolve it.  help me out , I'm just new to xaml

Comment: RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=-100}"> pls check out this

Comment: Check my code. You also had an error in the Width name (with capital W).

Comment: What is your problem? You had a compile error, with the code are you still having an error??